# Macro error in SharpDevelop - is not declared

Tags: macros, sharpdevelop, revit

This is my first time writing a macro so I'm not sure what this error means or how to fix it. Can anyone advise me? Any help would be appreciated. I would like to say I've tried a few solutions, but as I say, this is my first time so not sure what to even try.

```
Public Sub DeleteUnusedViews()
    'define current document
    Dim currentDoc As Document = Me.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document

    'get all views
    Dim viewCollector = New FilteredElementCollector(currentDoc)
    viewCollector.OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Sheets)

    'create list of views to delete
    Dim viewsToDelete As New List(Of View)

    'loop through views and check if it's on a sheet
    For Each curView As View In viewCollector
        'check if view is a template
        If curView.IsTemplate = False Then
            'check if view can be added to sheet
            If Viewport.CanAddViewToSheet(currentDoc, sheetCollector.FirstElement.Id, curView.Id) = True Then
                'add view to delete list
                viewsToDelete.Add(curView)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'create transaction
    Dim curTrans As New Transaction(currentDoc)
    curTrans.Start("Delete unused views")

    'delete views in list
    For Each curViewToDelete As View In viewsToDelete
        currentDoc.Delete(curViewToDelete.Id)
    Next

    'commit changes
    curTrans.Commit
    curTrans.Dispose

    'alert the user
    TaskDialog.Show("Deleted Views", "Deleted " & viewsToDelete.Count & " views.")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked in VB, but in a C# macro I've had to use this.ActiveUIDocument.Document to get the active document.

```
 Dim currentDoc As Document = this.ActiveUIDocument.Document
```

Perhaps 'Me' is not declared?
Also just noticed you intend to iterate through a collection of views but it looks likes your viewCollector is a collection of Elements that are ViewSheets.  Where is sheetCollector defined?